# jQuery mouseleave issues

Tags: jquery, menu, mouseleave

New to JQuery. I'm trying to make a menu where the links appear in a div that's in the same position when one of the categories in the menu is hovered over. I want the menu to stay open and disappear when the mouse leaves the menu. The problem I'm having is that every time "projects" is hovered over, none of the other menu categories open. I think this has something to do with "mouseleave" but I can't figure out the fix.

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="menuItem">
                <a id="press" href="#">Press</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menuItem">
                <a id="projects" href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menuItem">
                <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="wing" id="pressWing">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wing" id="contactWing">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Contact 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wing" id="projectsWing">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Project 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Project 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#contact').hover(function() {
        $('#contactWing').show();
    });
    $('#contactWing').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#contactWing').hide();
    })
    $('#projects').hover(function() {
        $('#projectsWing').show();
    });
    $('#projectsWing').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#projectsWing').hide();
    })
    $('#press').hover(function() {
        $('#pressWing').show();
    });
    $('#pressWing').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#pressWing').hide();
    })
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://codepen.io/maris170/pen/pogEXap

Comment: A better design is using nesting.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to do that and have the menu be positioned in the same place

Comment: So you want it to be some giant box under the list?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure 100% sure what exactly you are looking for, but the basic idea with CSS is using hover and nesting to show and hide its children UL

```css
nav ul,
nav li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* FIRST LEVEL */

nav > ul > li {
  float: left;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  padding: 0 2em;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

/* DROP DOWN */

nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left:0; /* remove this if you want it under the hovered option */
  width: 20em;
  background-color: #EDD;
}

nav > ul > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  min-height: 20em;
}

nav > ul > li > ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: .2em;
}

nav > ul > li > ul a:hover {
  background-color: #EAA;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="menuItem">
      <a id="press" href="#">Press</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li class="menuItem">
      <a id="projects" href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Project 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Project 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuItem">
      <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Contact 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Interesting...it works fine in codepen but once I use the code locally it doesn't work.

Comment: Just kidding--got it!